# Microsoft Graph To Do API: How to get only Outlook tasks?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-todo, outlook-graph-api

We have a solution built on the [Outlook Tasks API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlooktask?view=graph-rest-beta), which is now deprecated and will stop working in August 2022.

[image]

We'd like to transition to the To Do API with as low effort as possible (for now).

So how to we get the **Outlook tasks** from the To Do API? And only Outlook tasks. I see that the To Do API returns two task lists with the well-known names "flaggedEmails" and "defaultList". Outlook tasks are in there. But is it always only Outlook tasks?

How does a Microsoft To Do Graph API query look like that only returns tasks that were created in Outlook to match the behavior of the old Outlook tasks API (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 0):

The Query to get only the outlook tasks which were created and to fetch them using To DO list feature is currently not available, if you want this feature to be there you can raise a feature request :[New feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

Thanks.